# jQuery .val() is returning undefined on change of a select box

Tags: jquery

I have a select box with some dates. I want to get the value of said dates when the input changes. I keep getting undefined for my value.

```
$('#date_pick').change(function(){
            var values = $('#date_pick:selected').val();
            alert(values);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PJT6r/5/)

Comment: Wow, thanks everyone. I must be really out of it today. As soon as I saw these solutions I knew...I KNEW! D:

Comment: I just want to clarify that, getting the value of a `<select>` element (just like every other form element) is done with the `val()` function, so in this case => `$('#date_pick').val()`.

Comment: ^ Just to clarify, that wasn't working out for me for some odd reason so I went the route I did.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to put a space between the `#date_pick` and `:selected`.

```
var values = $('#date_pick :selected').val();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PJT6r/9/

Comment: Why now `$(this).val()` ?! -1

Comment: the fiddle is obviously just an example, he wants to get the value of the selected option... the other answers got it wrong

Comment: Actually, he doesn't need :selected there at all, although you're right that $('#date_pick :selected').val(); will work

Comment: Yeah...the university coffee shop is closed today due to Spring Break. :( I can't believe I missed this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Getting the value of a `<select>` element (just like every other form element), is done with the `val()` function.

So in your case => `$('#date_pick').val()`.

Note that in the change callback scope **you don't need to re-select the element**, `this` inside a callback is the DOM element that triggered the callback:

```
$('#date_pick').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PJT6r/10/)**

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove the 'selected'!

```
var values = $('#date_pick').val();
```

It's a caffeine issue, I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

or just `var values = $(this).val();`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the :selected bit in your selector
 Use:

```
$(function(){
        $('#date_pick').change(function(){
                    var values = $('#date_pick').val();
                    alert(values);
        });
});
```

​

Comment: Bit of an easy one.  I can see why people get confused with this though, because radio buttons and checkboxes don't work in quite the same way as select boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You can;

```
 var values = $('#date_pick option:selected').val();
```

Comment: The `option:selected` part of the selector is useless. you can safely delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting undefined/null values when trying to get value by ID. So I tried to get the selected value by **select field Name**.

```
<select name="date_pick" id="date_pick">
</select>
```

Then in jQuery,

```
$("select[name=date_pick]").val();
```

And result **NOT Getting undefined / null.**