# jQuery Get Selected Option From Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu

Usually I use `$("#id").val()` to return the value of the selected option, but this time it doesn't work.
The selected tag has the id `aioConceptName`

**html code**

```
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

<label for="aioConceptName">AIO Concept Name</label>
<select id="aioConceptName">
    <option>choose io</option>
    <option>roma</option>
    <option>totti</option>
</select>
```

Comment: could you show the markup of element `#aioConceptName`

Comment: it's strange because works on this example http://jsfiddle.net/pAtVP/, are you sure that the event it fires in your enviorment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Get selected option from dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380230/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Comment: A late thought, but .val() won't work unless you set the `value` attribute on those `<option>`s, right?

Comment: Recent versions of jQuery (tested with 1.9.1) have no issues with this markup. For the above example, `$("#aioConceptName").val()` returns `choose io`.

Comment: Doesn't it seem odd to ask a question about legit-broken code, and then to edit your question with the fix according to the correct answer, while not updating the statement that says it's broken?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap-select - how to fire event on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720986/bootstrap-select-how-to-fire-event-on-change)

Comment: @JacobValenta If an option doesn't have a `value` attribute, it defaults to the text.

Comment: for `.val()` you should add `value` attribute to `option` tags with  jQuery 
 method `.find(":selected")`, otherwise [following accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10659117/5803974) will work

Answer (score 2293, accepted):

For dropdown options you probably want something like this:

**For selected text**

```
var conceptName = $('#aioConceptName').find(":selected").text();
```

**For selected value**

```
var conceptName = $('#aioConceptName').find(":selected").val();
```

The reason `val()` doesn't do the trick is because clicking an option doesn't change the value of the dropdown--it just adds the `:selected` property to the selected option which is a *child* of the dropdown.

Comment: Ah, okay, you've updated your question with HTML. This answer is now irrelevant. As a matter of fact, `.val()` should work in your case-- you must have an error elsewhere.

Comment: for the `val()` why not use `var conceptVal = $("#aioConceptName option").filter(":selected").val();`?

Comment: How about a simpler `var conceptVal = $("#aioConceptName option:selected").val()`?

Comment: @techouse That may look simpler, but Web Storm tells your method is "inefficient use of jQuery" and recommends breaking it up. Which I'm actually curious as to why. Must be Crockford's orders.

Comment: Other option would be: `var text = $("select#my_id option:selected").text()` (not using `.val()` as said by @techouse).

Comment: @DiegoLago: Actually, it's not the `.val()` that's the issue there, so replacing it with `.text()` doesn't make much of a difference. The drawback is the long selector, I believe.

Comment: I still found this helpful for finding the selected option in a select where I've obtained the dropdown previously -- e.g., `var mySelect = $('#mySelect');` _/* ... more code happens ... */_ `var selectedText = mySelect.find(':selected').text();`

Comment: `.val` works with `<select multiple>` and returns an array with all selected values. Just dropping by as the answer threw me off a bit when working with multiple select.

Comment: Or we could just use - `$('#aioConceptName option:selected').text()` or `$('#aioConceptName :selected').text()`

Comment: I had extra data values in my option that I needed to access, like `<option value=1 data-email=foo@bar.com>Foo</option>`, and like @Curious, I also already had the control passed into a jQuery variable, so using `contact_element.find(":selected").data("email")` worked great for me.

Comment: $(this).find("option:selected")

Comment: Actually the reason .val() isn't working for him is because he didn't actually give his options a value, which is why he has to use your method to retrieve the selected text, so another fix would've been to change <option>choose io</option>
to <option value='choose io'>choose io</option>
Although your solution is probably quicker and more practical, I figured I'd state this anyways so he has a better understanding of why it wasn't working for him.

Comment: Probably good to know that **setting the select option** by value works by using `$("#selector").val("2");` or `$("#selector option[value='2']").prop('selected', true);` and by its text instead: https://stackoverflow.com/q/496052/1066234

Comment: Any idea how can I get the value of any option not just the selected option?

Comment: @KrishnaveniB You can access all the options in an array by doing `$("#aioConceptName").find("option")`. To access a specific child's value, use `$("#aioConceptName").find("option")[0].value`.

Comment: This answer is wrong. If an option doesn't have a `value` attribute, its value defaults to its text. And the value of a `<select>` is the value of the selected `<option>`, so you don't need to use `option:selected`.

Comment: One of the best too is to always add the option `value` to each `option` tag so you can get value from `$('#aioConceptName').val();`. And of course you can pass the value into hidden input by detecting `onchange` on `#aioConceptName`.
I like this answer from @ElliotBonneville to gives you the solution.

Answer (score 428):

**Set the values for each of the options**

```
<label for="aioConceptName">AIO Concept Name</label>
<select id="aioConceptName">
    <option value="0">choose io</option>
    <option value="1">roma</option>
    <option value="2">totti</option>
</select>
```

`$('#aioConceptName').val()` didn't work because `.val()` returns the `value` attribute. To have it work properly, the `value` attributes must be set on each `<option>`.

Now you can call `$('#aioConceptName').val()` instead of all this `:selected` voodoo being suggested by others.

Comment: Caveat: if no option is selected, `$('#aioConceptName').val()` returns null/"undefined"

Comment: This assured me that $('#myselect').val() was correct I'd just dumbly forgotten to give the select an id!

Comment: One of my select options is a special `prompt` option `<option>Please select an option</option>`. In my case it wasn't a problem to add a blank value attribute `<option value="">Please...</option>` but I believe in some cases not having a value attribute makes sense. But +1 because your vodoo wording made me smile.

Comment: Isn't `val()` select the `value` instead of the text inside the `option`? I.e. it selects `1` instead of `roma`.

Comment: @deathlock That's the whole point of `.val()`. If you are looking to manipulate/use the text, use `$(":selected).text()` or set the value and the text to be the same.

Answer (score 208):

I stumbled across this question and developed a more concise version of Elliot BOnneville's answer:

```
var conceptName = $('#aioConceptName :selected').text();
```

or generically:

```
$('#id :pseudoclass')
```

This saves you an extra jQuery call, selects everything in one shot, and is more clear (my opinion).

Comment: @JohnConde The accepted answer on Meta disagrees with you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource .  In my opinion, Ed has given a good answer and just provided some extra reference.

Comment: They can allow it but it's still a bad resource

Comment: Removed the w3schools link, it wasn't strictly necessary and a Google search for "jQuery pseduo classes" provides plenty of information.

Comment: @EdOrsi: While it saves an extra jQuery call, it prevents from taking taking advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method (see [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)). So, it should be slower than the [Eliot's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10659117/3345644).

Comment: I'd probably favor using `.find(':selected')` as then it allows you do call it from a callback attached to an event... like `$('#aioConceptname').bind('change', function(el) { console.log ( $(el).find(':selected').text() ); });`

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov : Cuz `:selected` is a jQuery **extension** and is thus slow, we can use `:checked` instead. `:checked` maps to the in-built CSS functionality, and so does not take the performance hit that `:selected` takes.

Answer (score 73):

Try this for value...

```
$("select#id_of_select_element option").filter(":selected").val();
```

or this for text...

```
$("select#id_of_select_element option").filter(":selected").text();
```

Comment: When use multi select dropdown it only get first value

Comment: @ThimiraPathirana In that case you just get rid of the "option" word from the query.

Answer (score 67):

If you are in event context, in jQuery, you can retrieve the selected option element using :
`$(this).find('option:selected')` like this :

```
$('dropdown_selector').change(function() {
    //Use $option (with the "$") to see that the variable is a jQuery object
    var $option = $(this).find('option:selected');
    //Added with the EDIT
    var value = $option.val();//to get content of "value" attrib
    var text = $option.text();//to get <option>Text</option> content
});
```

**Edit**

As mentioned by [PossessWithin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4781067/possesswithin), My answer just answer to the question : How to select selected "Option".

Next, to get the option value, use `option.val()`.

Comment: Flawless! Just do not forget you should add `$(this).find('option:selected').val()` at the end to get the value of the option element, or `$(this).find('option:selected').text()` to get the text. :)

Comment: The most elegant and simple answer.

Comment: These days, you could add "event" as a parameter for that anonymous function, and then get the value of the select list on change using "event.target.value"

Answer (score 40):

Have you considered using plain old javascript?

```
var box = document.getElementById('aioConceptName');

conceptName = box.options[box.selectedIndex].text;
```

See also [Getting an option text/value with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641962/getting-an-option-text-value-with-javascript)

Comment: ˗1 not enough jQuery

Answer (score 36):

```
$('#aioConceptName option:selected').val();
```

Comment: This is best answer of all, wish there was a way at stack overflow to request to show up the correct answers at the top.

Answer (score 21):

With **JQuery**:

1. If you want to get the selected option **text**, you can use `$(select element).text()`.

   `var text = $('#aioConceptName option:selected').text();`
2. If you want to get selected option **value**, you can use `$(select element).val()`.

   `var val = $('#aioConceptName option:selected').val();`

   Make sure to set `value` attribute in `<option>` tag, like:

   ```
   <select id="aioConceptName">
     <option value="">choose io</option>
     <option value="roma(value)">roma(text)</option>
     <option value="totti(value)">totti(text)</option>
   </select>
   ```

With this HTML code sample, assuming **last option is selected**:

1. ***var text*** will give you `totti(text)`
2. ***var val*** will give you `totti(value)`

```js
$(document).on('change','#aioConceptName' ,function(){
  var val = $('#aioConceptName option:selected').val();
  var text = $('#aioConceptName option:selected').text();
  $('.result').text("Select Value = " + val);
  $('.result').append("<br>Select Text = " + text);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="aioConceptName">
 <option value="io(value)">choose io</option>
 <option value="roma(value)">roma(text)</option>
 <option value="totti(value)">totti(text)</option>
</select>

<p class="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 20):

For good practice you need to use `val()` to get value of selected options not `text()`.

```
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" />
<select id="aioConceptName">
    <option value="choose">choose io</option>
</select>
```

You can use

```
   $("#aioConceptName").find(':selected').val();
```

Or

```
   $("#aioConceptName :selected").val();
```

Answer (score 18):

**Reading the value (not the text) of a select:**

```
var status = $("#Status").val();
var status = $("#Status")[0].value;
var status = $('#Status option:selected').val();
```

**How to disable a select?** 
in both variants, value can be changed using:

**A**

User can not interact with the dropdown. And he doesn't know what other options might exists.

```
$('#Status').prop('disabled', true);
```

**B**

User can see the options in the dropdown but all of them are disabled:

```
$('#Status option').attr('disabled', true);
```

In this case, `$("#Status").val()` **will only work** for jQuery versions smaller than `1.9.0`. All other variants will work.

**How to update a disabled select?**

From code behind you can still update the value in your select. It is disabled only for users:

```
$("#Status").val(2);
```

In some cases you might need to fire events:

```
$("#Status").val(2).change();
```

Comment: When use multi select dropdown it only get first value

Answer (score 15):

you should use this syntax:

```
var value = $('#Id :selected').val();
```

So try this Code:

```
var values = $('#aioConceptName :selected').val();
```

you can test in Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PJT6r/9/

see about this answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771728/jquery-val-is-returning-undefined-on-change-of-a-select-box)

Answer (score 14):

to find correct selections with jQuery consider multiple selections can be available in html trees and confuse your expected output.

`(:selected).val()` or `(:selected).text()` will **not** work correct on multiple select options. So we keep an array of all selections first like `.map()` could do and then return the desired argument or text.

The following example illustrates those problems and offers a better approach

```
<select id="form-s" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected>city1</option>
    <option selected value="c2">city2</option>
    <option value="c3">city3</option>
</select>   
<select id="aioConceptName">
    <option value="s1" selected >choose io</option>
    <option value="s2">roma </option>
    <option value="s3">totti</option>
</select>
<select id="test">
    <option value="s4">paloma</option>
    <option value="s5" selected >foo</option>
    <option value="s6">bar</option>
</select>
<script>
$('select').change(function() {
    var a=$(':selected').text(); // "city1city2choose iofoo"
    var b=$(':selected').val();  // "city1" - selects just first query !
    //but..
    var c=$(':selected').map(function(){ // ["city1","city2","choose io","foo"]
        return $(this).text();
    }); 
    var d=$(':selected').map(function(){ // ["city1","c2","s1","s5"]
        return $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(a,b,c,d);
});
</script>
```

see the different bug prone output in variant **a, b** compared to correctly working **c & d** that keep all selections in an array and then return what you look for.

Answer (score 13):

Using jQuery, just add a `change` event and get selected value or text within that handler.

If you need selected text, please use this code:

```
$("#aioConceptName").change(function () {
    alert($("#aioConceptName :selected").text())
});
```

Or if you need selected value, please use this code:

```
$("#aioConceptName").change(function () {
    alert($("#aioConceptName :selected").attr('value'))
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Just this should work:

```
var conceptName = $('#aioConceptName').val();
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#aioConceptName').on('change', function(event) {
    console.log(event.type + " event with:", $(this).val());
    $(this).prev('input').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" />
<select id="aioConceptName">
  <option>choose io</option>
  <option>roma</option>
  <option>totti</option>
</select>
```

Comment: added snippet as proof of concept for this

Answer (score 11):

For anyone who found out that best answer don't work.

Try to use:

```
  $( "#aioConceptName option:selected" ).attr("value");
```

Works for me in recent projects so it is worth to look on it.

Answer (score 10):

Use the [`jQuery.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function for select elements, too:

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea. In the case of select elements, it
>   returns `null` when no option is selected and an array containing the
>   value of each selected option when there is at least one and it is
>   possible to select more because the `multiple` attribute is present.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#aioConceptName").on("change", function() {
    $("#debug").text($("#aioConceptName").val());
  }).trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="aioConceptName">
  <option>choose io</option>
  <option>roma</option>
  <option>totti</option>
</select>
<div id="debug"></div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Straight forward and pretty easy:

*Your dropdown*

```
<select id="aioConceptName">
    <option>choose io</option>
    <option>roma</option>
    <option>totti</option>
</select>
```

*Jquery code to get the selected value*

```
$('#aioConceptName').change(function() {
    var $option = $(this).find('option:selected');

    //Added with the EDIT
    var value = $option.val(); //returns the value of the selected option.
    var text = $option.text(); //returns the text of the selected option.
});
```

Answer (score 10):

For get *value* of tag selected:

```
 $('#id_Of_Parent_Selected_Tag').find(":selected").val();
```

And if you want to get *text* use this code:

```
 $('#id_Of_Parent_Selected_Tag').find(":selected").text();
```

**For Example:**

```
<div id="i_am_parent_of_select_tag">
<select>
        <option value="1">CR7</option>
        <option value="2">MESSI</option>
</select>
</div>


<script>
 $('#i_am_parent_of_select_tag').find(":selected").val();//OUTPUT:1 OR 2
 $('#i_am_parent_of_select_tag').find(":selected").text();//OUTPUT:CR7 OR MESSI
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

I hope this also helps to understand better and helps 
try this below,

```
$('select[id="aioConceptName[]"] option:selected').each(function(key,value){
   options2[$(this).val()] = $(this).text();
   console.log(JSON.stringify(options2));
});
```

to more details please 
http://www.drtuts.com/get-value-multi-select-dropdown-without-value-attribute-using-jquery/

Answer (score 5):

You can try to debug it this way:

```
console.log($('#aioConceptName option:selected').val())
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to grab the 'value' attribute instead of the text node, this will work for you:

```
var conceptName = $('#aioConceptName').find(":selected").attr('value');
```

Comment: This is only partially a solution - it is also necessary to set the value for each option - this is already covered by Jacob Valetta's answer

Answer (score 4):

Here is the simple solution for this issue.

```
$("select#aioConceptName").change(function () {
           var selectedaioConceptName = $('#aioConceptName').find(":selected").val();;
           console.log(selectedaioConceptName);
        });
```

Comment: ```var selectedaioConceptName = $('#aioConceptName option:selected').val();``` is better than use another find()

Answer (score 4):

You many try this:

```js
var ioConceptName = $('#ioConceptName option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 3):

try to this one

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#name option").filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() == $("#firstname").val();
    }).attr('selected', true);

    $("#name").live("change", function() {

        $("#firstname").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
    });
});


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="name" name="name"> 
<option value="">Please select...</option> 
<option value="Elvis">Elvis</option> 
<option value="Frank">Frank</option> 
<option value="Jim">Jim</option> 
</select>

<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="Elvis" readonly="readonly">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('nameofDropDownList').prop('selectedIndex', whateverNumberasInt);
```

Imagine the DDL as an array with indexes, you are selecting one index. Choose the one which you want to set it to with your JS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$("#drpList").val();`

Comment: You were right; however, he related to the text, the question is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

to fetch a select with same class= name you could do this, to check if a select option is selected.

```
var bOK = true;
$('.optKategorien').each(function(index,el){
    if($(el).find(":selected").text() == "") {
        bOK = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I figured out why it was not working on my case
The html page was divided into different html fragments and I found that I have another input field that carries the same Id of the `select`, which caused the `val()` to be always empty
I hope this saves the day for anyone who have similar issue.

Comment: Indeed, this woke me to my problem. I was myself using qty-field in the data-target and.. qty_field in the id itself. Always check the basics twice or more.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
aioConceptName.selectedOptions[0].value
```

```js
let val = aioConceptName.selectedOptions[0].value

console.log('selected value:',val);
```

```html
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" />
<select id="aioConceptName">
    <option>choose io</option>
    <option>roma</option>
    <option>totti</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this vanilla js, question asked specifically for jQuery solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one correct way to find selected option - by `option` `value` attribute. So take the simple code:

```
//find selected option
$select = $("#mySelect");
$selectedOption = $select.find( "option[value=" + $select.val() + "]" );
//get selected option text
console.log( $selectedOption.text() );
```

So if you have list like this:

```
<select id="#mySelect" >
  <option value="value1" >First option</option>
  <option value="value2" >Second option</option>
  <option value="value3" selected >Third option</option>
</select>
```

If you use `selected` attribute for `option`, then `find(":selected")` will give incorrect result because `selected` attribute will stay at `option` forever, even user selects another option.

Even if user will selects first or second option, the result of $("select option:selected") will give **two elements**! So $("select :selected").text() will give a result like "*First option Third option*"

So use `value` attribute selector and don't forget to set `value` attribute for all options!

Answer (score 2):

1. Use  **name** attribute of the **select** element.

   `<select name="myName"></select>`
2. `$('select[name=myName]').val()`

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best bet with this kind of scenario is to use [jQuery's change method](https://api.jquery.com/change/) to find the currently selected value, like so:

```
$('#aioConceptName').change(function(){

   //get the selected val using jQuery's 'this' method and assign to a var
   var selectedVal = $(this).val();

   //perform the rest of your operations using aforementioned var

});
```

I prefer this method because you can then perform functions for each selected option in a given select field.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'd need to not only get the selected value, but also run some action. So why not avoid all the jQuery magic and just pass the selected value as an argument to the action call?

```
<select onchange="your_action(this.value)">
   <option value='*'>All</option>
   <option ... />
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select using exact selected option : 
Below will give innerText

```
$("select#aioConceptName > option:selected").text()
```

While below will give you value.

```
$("select#aioConceptName > option:selected").val()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code: :)

get value:

```
 $("#Ostans option:selected").val() + '.' + $("#shahrha option:selected").val()
```

get text:

```
 $("#Ostans option:selected").text() + '.' + $("#shahrha option:selected").text()
```

Comment: which one do we believe? 's' in ostans or 'ha' in shahrha? :D

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use this.

```
$('#aioConceptName').find('option:selected')
```