# How to retrieve a value of a selected Item from a dropdown List?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql

How to i get a value of a selected ITEM from a drop down list ? I'm reading my values a SQL Table using a Stored Procedure ,Once the list is populated i want to take the selected ITEM and save the SQL TABLE. Any help will be much appreciated. Here is what i've tried :

```
function QueryKomaxDetails() {
    $.ajax({
        url: GET_SCHEDULE_DEPARTMENTS,
        data: 'includeInactive=' + null,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: LoadKomaxDetails
    });
}

var LoadKomaxDetails = function (data) {
    var dllItems = eval(data);
    var komaxDetails = $("#ddlItems").val();
    $.each(dllItems, function () {
        komaxDetails.append("<option value='" + this.departmentId + "'>" + this.departmentName + "</option>");
    });
}
```

And i managed to get ITEM as a dropdown list.
Here is my HTML code as follows :

```
<label>Select Komax :</label><select id="ddlItems" name="komax" ></select>
```

Comment: Watch out, `eval(data)` might be a security hole if `data` can be manipulated by users. Actually, isn't jQuery will automatically change it to an Object by default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery get selected option from dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var komaxDetails = $("#ddlItems");
$.each(dllItems, function () {
        komaxDetails.append("<option value='" + this.departmentId + "'>" + this.departmentName + "</option>");
});
```

Comment: By using eval i'm deserializing  the data ,how i'm gonna those values if i remove it ?

Comment: What exactly you gets in "data"?? bcz using eval is not a good practise!