# Bootstrap-select - how to fire event on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0.2 and the [Bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) plugin.

**Here's my select list**:

```html
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-size="7">
  <option>Petr Karel</option>
  <option>Honza Novák</option>
  <option>David Egydy</option>
  <option>Sláva Kovář</option>
  <option>Hana Skalická</option>
  <option>Simona Kolářová</option>
  <option>Kateřina Sychová</option>
  <option>Amálka Sychová</option>
  <option>Jana Sychová</option>
  <option>Magdaléna Sychová</option>
  <option>Tereza Sychová</option>
  <option>Bohdana Sychová</option>
</select>
```

**Here's my JavaScript**:

```js
//inicialization of select picker
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

//on change function i need to control selected value
$('select.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
   var selected = $('.selectpicker option:selected').val();
   alert(selected);
});
```

#### Issue

My problem is that change function won't work. It doesn't do anything, and I can't find solution by myself.

If i put it into document ready instead change function it seems to be working. So i guess i have mistake somewhere in:

```
$('select.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
```

I also tried to use only:

```
$('.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
```

without this select prefix but nothing changes.

#### UPDATE

Solution is putting jquery code into `document.ready()`. Thanks to [Kartikeya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3852595/kartikeya)

Comment: why you are not putting jquery code in document.ready()..???

Answer (score 121):

When Bootstrap Select initializes, it'll build a set of custom divs that run alongside the original `<select>` element and will typically synchronize state between the two input mechanisms.

[image: BS Select Elements]

Which is to say that one way to handle events on bootstrap select is to listen for events on the original select that it modifies, regardless of who updated it.

### Solution 1 - Native Events

Just listen for a [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) and get the selected value [using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1085801/1366033) or [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10659097/1366033) like this:

```js
$('select').on('change', function(e){
  console.log(this.value,
              this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,
              $(this).find("option:selected").val(),);
});
```

<sup>***NOTE**: As with any script reliant on the DOM, make sure you wait for the [DOM ready event](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) before executing</sup>

#### Demo in Stack Snippets:

```js
$(function() {

  $('select').on('change', function(e){
    console.log(this.value,
                this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,
                $(this).find("option:selected").val(),);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker">
  <option val="Must"> Mustard </option>
  <option val="Cat" > Ketchup </option>
  <option val="Rel" > Relish  </option>
</select>
```

### Solution 2 - Bootstrap Select Custom Events

As [this answer alludes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36944647/1366033), Bootstrap Select has their own set of [custom events](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/#events), including `changed.bs.select` which:

> fires after the select's value has been changed. It passes through event, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue.

And you can use that like this:

```js
$("select").on("changed.bs.select", 
      function(e, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(this.value, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue)
});
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets:

```js
$(function() {

  $("select").on("changed.bs.select", 
        function(e, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log(this.value, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue)
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker">
  <option val="Must"> Mustard </option>
  <option val="Cat" > Ketchup </option>
  <option val="Rel" > Relish  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: **Another solution** This doesn't get's the value of last `un-selected` option, so instead try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944647/bootstrap-select-on-click-get-clicked-value)

Comment: @stom, good point, I've inlined bits from that answer and identified the differences between both

Comment: please edit to change `val=` to `value=` in the option tags.

Answer (score 34):

This is what I did.

```
$('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function (e, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue) {
    var selected = $(e.currentTarget).val();
});
```

Comment: **Another solution** This doesn't get's the value of last `un-selected` option, so instead try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944647/bootstrap-select-on-click-get-clicked-value)

Answer (score 9):

Simplest solution would be -

`$('.selectpicker').trigger('change');`

Answer (score 8):

```
$("#Id").change(function(){
    var selected = $('#Id option:selected').val();
    alert(selected);           
});
```

I think this is what you need.

Comment: how to get all the values if multiselect?

Answer (score 4):

Easiest implementation.

```
<script>
    $( ".selectpicker" ).change(function() {
        alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My implementation

```
import $ from 'jquery';

$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#whatDescribesYouSelectInput').on('change', (e) => {
    if (e.target.value === 'Other') {
      $('#whatDescribesYouOtherInput').attr('type', 'text');
      $('#specifyLabel').show();
    } else {
      $('#whatDescribesYouOtherInput').attr('type', 'hidden');
      $('#specifyLabel').hide();
    }
  });
});
```