# Get the current value in bootstrap-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html-select, bootstrap-select

I used `e.target.value` to retrieve the current selected value from bootstrap-select but it returned the first selected value i.e. the alert kept displaying item 1, when item 1 and item 2 where selected even when item 2 was the most recently selected.

How can I get the value for the recent selection and how can I get how many options are selected?

```
   <select multiple class="selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count > 1">
    <option value="item 1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="item 2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="item 3">Item 3</option>
    <option value="item 4">Item 4</option>
    <option value="item 5">Item 5</option>
```

```
$('.selectpicker').change(function (e) {
    alert(e.target.value);
});
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think the answer may be easier to understand like this:

```js
$('#empid').on('click',function() {
  alert($(this).val());
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="empid" name="empname" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="0">item0</option>
  <option value="1">item1</option>
  <option value="2">item2</option>
  <option value="3">item3</option>
  <option value="4">item4</option>
</select>
<br />
Hold CTRL / CMD for selecting multiple fields
```

If you select "item1" and "item2" in the list, the output will be "1,2".

Comment: I am getting all selected values or text, I want to have only the currently selected value, not like 'item 1 item 2' when I clicked 'item2'.

Comment: the code will result only current selected value if it is one it will show 1 if its multiple it will show all

Comment: Yes, it is set multiple, How can I get the last clicked value?

Comment: your question is like getting current selected value ? now you are asking last selected value ?

Comment: the currently selected value.  It is the same with the last clicked value, isn't it?

Comment: check now if you click on one value for more then one time it ll show them as many time

Answer (score 29):

instead of `e.target.value`, you can use `$(this).find("option:selected").text();`

```js
 $('.selectpicker').change(function () {
        var selectedItem = $('.selectpicker').val();
        alert(selectedItem);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count > 1">
 <option value="1">Item 1</option>
 <option value="2">Item 2</option>
 <option value="3">Item 3</option>
 <option value="4">Item 4</option>
 <option value="5">Item 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this isn't true because in many cases the value isn't the same as the text, in my case anyway!

Comment: yes you are right. Both are not always necessary to be same

Answer (score 10):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720986/bootstrap-select-how-to-fire-event-on-change), you should do something like :

```
$('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {
    var selected = e.target.value;
});
```

Answer (score 10):

```
$('.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
    var selected = []
    selected = $('.selectpicker').val()
    console.log(selected); //Get the multiple values selected in an array
    console.log(selected.length); //Length of the array
});
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the Solution:

```
$('#payment_method').on('hidden.bs.select', function (e) {
  // console.log(e.target.value);

  console.log(e.target.selectedOptions.length);

$.each( e.target.selectedOptions , function( index, obj ){
    console.log(obj.value);
});

});
```

You get the length of the selections, so may be helpful in for loop

```
console.log(e.target.selectedOptions.length);
```

and you can loop through the selected values too:

```
$.each( e.target.selectedOptions , function( index, obj ){
    console.log(obj.value);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I get the value of selected Item from select list:

```
var e = document.getElementById("field_ID");  
var selected_value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
 $('.selectpicker').change(function () {
        var selectedItem = $('.selectpicker').val();
        alert(selectedItem);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count > 1">
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
    <option value="4">Item 4</option>
    <option value="5">Item 5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case you need to take the value. I use jQuery to help for this:

```js
$('.selectpicker').change(function (e) {
    alert($(e.target).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution might help somebody

*The option value isn't always the same as the text*

```
$('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function () {
    let val = $(this).siblings('.btn.dropdown-toggle').attr('title');
    console.log(val);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Bootstrap-select documentation](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/) you can use:

```
const selected = $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val');

console.log(selected); //display selected option values as array
console.log(selected.length); // display number of selected options
console.log(selected.at(-1)); // display the most recently selected option
```

Answer (score 0):

after my try, i found there are two ways to get the current selected value.

1. `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val')`
   in the office document, it only say set value through  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', [0, 1]);  so i guess .selectpicker('val') would return selected val. and i try it, it works.
2. use `$(this).val()` inside event listen function, as @Mirza Obaid mention
   `$('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function (e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue) { const selectedVal = $(this).val(); }`