# Get selected value from a select in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the `selected value` from a `select`.

```
<select name="customer-country">
  <option value="CA">Canada</option>
  <option value="FR">France</option>
</select >
```

My problem is the code given in jQuery.com do not work.

```
alert($("input[name=customer-country]").val());
```

Any clue ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Get Selected Option From Dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the query to something like

```
$('select[name=customer-country]').val();
```

since a select is not a input

Comment: @teamo GRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR!

Answer (score 0):

select is not an input

```js
$('select').on(
  "change", 
  function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="customer-country">
  <option value="CA">Canada</option>
  <option value="FR">France</option>
</select >
```

Answer (score 0):

try select

```
alert($("select[name=customer-country]").val())
```