# javascript error: Cannot read property 'options' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a GridView that has a column with a textbox where the user can enter a value and a column with a dropdownlist. If the user enter a values that is not equal to 1 in the textbox, they must select a value from the dropdownlist. The default value in the DDL is "Select" which is just an empty value that was coded in: `ddlReasons.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select"));`. The DDL is created dynamically but select will always be the default value.

```
 function UpdateSerialQtyRcvd(SerNoID, QtyRcvd) {
        if (QtyRcvd != 1) {
            var ddl = document.getElementById("ddlReasons");
            var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
            if (selectedValue == "Select") {
                alert("Must select reason");
            }

        }
        else {
            PageMethods.UpdateSerialQtyRcvdUserControl(SerNoID, QtyRcvd, OnUpdateSuccess, OnUpdateFail);
        }
    }
```

If the user enters a value that is not 1 then I need to check what value is in the DDL. If "Select" is the value I need the user to select something else in the DDL but I am getting this error on the line `var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;`

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null

Code for dropdownlist:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reason">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlReasons" runat="server" class="ReasonDDL" ></asp:DropDownList>
 </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Try with jquery to get the selected value from drop down. [jQuery Get Selected Option From Dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown) like `var selectedValue = $('#ddlReasons').find(":selected").text();` or `var selectedValue = $('#ddlReasons :selected').text();`

Comment: `document.getElementById("ddlReasons");` returns null, i.e. your dropdown couldn't be found. Post the relevant HTML.

Comment: the dropdown should have unique Id, since you are using the dropdown in a GridView, you need to access the dropdown by class Name

Comment: Is `"ddlReasons"` the `ClientID` of the dropdown control?

Comment: @phuzi code for dropdownlist added

Comment: @Braj I added the code you suggested but when checking `if (selectedValue == "Select")` selectedValue is " "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get the **ClientId**...

**Javascript**:

```
var ddl = document.getElementById("<%=ddlReasons.ClientID%>");
```

**JQuery**:

```
var ddl = $('#<%=ddlReasons.ClientID%>');
```

Check out the [`MSDN documentation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd410598(v=vs.100).aspx) on how to access the Client ID and the different settings.

Comment: I am getting the error: The name 'ddlReasons' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @user123456789 Inspect your dropdown and see the id of the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do it using **JQuery** :

```
var ddlReason = $("[id*=ddlReasons]");
var selectedValue = ddlReason.val();
```