# Using $('#id').val() doesn't return the selected value of a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find the selected value of a dropdown but I keep getting an empty string or undefined results.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="input-group" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <span id="add-addon-styling" class="input-group-addon">Status</span>
    <!-- TODO: Make this automatically rather than hardcoded -->
    <select class="form-control required" id="new-activity-modal-status-dropdown">
        <option value="NA" class="selected">N/A</option>
        <option value="ON_TRACK">On Track</option>
        <option value="ISSUE">Issue</option>
        <option value="BEHIND">Behind</option>
    </select>
    <span class="input-group-addon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="The Status of the Activity. Usually On Track but otherwise set to N/A if unsure.">
        <b>?</b>
    </span>
</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
function OnModalCreateNewActivityBtnClick() {
    var jsonObject = '';
    var modal = $('new-activity-modal-body');
    var activityStatus = modal.find('#new-activity-modal-status-dropdown').val();
    ...
    ...
}
```

I've also seen this suggested:

```
function OnModalCreateNewActivityBtnClick() {
    var jsonObject = '';
    var modal = $('new-activity-modal-body');
    var activityStatus = modal.find('#new-activity-modal-status-dropdown').find(":selected").text();
    ...
    ...
}
```

The first returns an undefined result. The second returns an empty string.

I'm not sure what to do. JavaScript still perplexes me.

Comment: use `selector` `#` for `id` here `$('new-activity-modal-body');`

Comment: Here is maybe your solution :
[StackOverflow jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Comment: Whoever put a minus on the post, would you mind explaining why, so I can avoid it in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var modal = $('new-activity-modal-body');
```

Should probably be

```
var modal = $('#new-activity-modal-body');
```

You get no errors, since jquery selectors finding nothing is a valid situtation.

Comment: Yep that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the HTML is :

```
<div class="new-activity-modal-body">...</div>
```

The following code will not work because you don't specify if `new-activity-modal-body` is a `class` or `id` :

```
var modal = $('new-activity-modal-body');
```

Should be :

```
var modal = $('#new-activity-modal-body'); //id selector
//OR
var modal = $('.new-activity-modal-body'); //class selector
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var modal = $('#new-activity-modal-body');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `modal` is not assigned properly. There is no `new-activity-modal-body`. You should use `#new-activity-modal-body`.

Just replace

```
var modal = $('new-activity-modal-body');
```

With

```
var modal = $('#new-activity-modal-body');
```