# display data related to a dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down list

```
<select name="column_select" id="column_select">
<option value="col1">1 column</option>
<option value="col2">2 column</option>
<option value="col3">3 column</option>
</select>
```

On clicking an option i want to display the details of the particular option in the same page.

How can this be implemented using jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Get Selected Option From Dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function showval(value) 
{
  
  var text = $("#column_select option:selected").text();
  
  var string = "Value is: "+value+" and Text is: "+text;
  
  $("#showvalue").html(string);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showvalue">
</div>


<select name="column_select" id="column_select" onchange="showval(this.value);">
<option value="col1">1 column</option>
<option value="col2">2 column</option>
<option value="col3">3 column</option>
</select>
```

It should help you.

Answer (score 0):

use this jquery

**jquery**

```
$('select.column_select').on('change', function(){
  var selectVal = $(this).val();
  if(selectVal==col1){
    // do something
  };
  if(selectVal==col2){
    // do something
  };
  if(selectVal==col3){
    // do something
  };
});
```

Comment: hey i have a div and some content for every value. how to show the content of the div only when the value matches

Comment: wrap different content in different inner div's with different classes and show the classes accordingly in above code...if you can create a fiddle and share your code i can code for u :)

Comment: hey i did something similar and the code worked now , i basically did a hide on the siblings and display on the div vased on the value selected . I did create a fiidle but no idea why it isnt working der.. https://jsfiddle.net/r80r8jrc/ Here is my fiddle.

Comment: But how do i tackle it if i am fetching the data from db , the i would just be creating one generalized div and generate dynamic data. How would the id's work then?

Comment: i cant see the included jquery liberary here...have u included it in your code??

Comment: bro u were doing some code mistaked...here is the updated fiddle u were missed with one bracket https://jsfiddle.net/yudi/r80r8jrc/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the change event for the select and perform the details display based on the current value in the select:

```
$("#column_select").on("change", function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    // logic based on selected value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$(document).on('change','#column_select',function() {
   // Code to write it anywhere on page. 
   // If you want it to write on `span#spnDisplay` then use this
   var selText = $('#column_select option:selected').text();
   $('#spnDisplay').text(selText)
});
```