# How do I get the text value of a selected option?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, css-selectors

as the question says, i would like to get the value of the selected value and display the value within a dropdown list if possible. i have attempt but do not seem to get anywhere

```
<div class="products-prices-calculators-wrap">

            <label for="js-data">Quantity: </label>
            <select id="js-data" <option value="<?php echo $product_min_quantity ?>" </option> </select>



jQuery('#js-data')change(function () {
    var selectedOption = $('js-dataoptions:selected');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Get Selected Option From Dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Comment: if you are using onchange than it will already give u selected one

Comment: check the [:selected Selector](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) it allow you to get the selected item...

Comment: why is this even tagged as PHP?

Answer (score 1):

It is simple

```
var val = $( "#js-QuantityInputs" ).val();
```

or you can use this

```
$("#js-QuantityInputs option:selected").text();
```

Following lines you have missed '>' at end of the tag

```
<select id="js-QuantityInputs"
<option value="<?php echo $product_min_quantity ?>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues in your `HTML` and `jQuery`.

1. `<select>` box not close properly.
2. `<option>` tag not close properly.
3. syntax error in `jQuery` near `onchange` event.

**Modified Code:**

```
<select id="js-QuantityInputs">
    <option value="<?php echo $product_min_quantity; ?>">
        <?php echo $product_min_quantity; ?> 
    </option> 
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#js-QuantityInputs" ).change(function() {
      var selectedOption = $('#js-QuantityInputs').val();     
    });
</script>
```

**Side note:** make sure you are using jQuery library file in your template.