# How to get selected option data attribute from HTML select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the below code. Why am I not able to get the selected option's data attribute?

```js
$('#type-picker').on('change', function (e) {
  var filter =  $(this).data("filter");
  console.log(filter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker" id="type-picker" data-width="100%" >
  <option data-filter="na" >Select From The List</option>
  <option data-filter="*">Display ALl</option>
  <option data-filter=".type1">Relish</option>
  <option data-filter=".type2">Relish</option>
  <option data-filter=".type3">Relish</option>
</select>
```

Comment: In that context, `this` represents the `<select>` element, not the selected `option`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Get Selected Option From Dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this)` will return the select itself, which has no `data-filter`, you need to get the selected option to obtain its filter attribute

```js
$('#type-picker').on('change', function (e) {
  var filter =  $(this).find('option:selected').data("filter");
  console.log(filter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker" id="type-picker" data-width="100%" >
  <option data-filter="na" >Select From The List</option>
  <option data-filter="*">Display ALl</option>
  <option data-filter=".type1">Relish</option>
  <option data-filter=".type2">Relish</option>
  <option data-filter=".type3">Relish</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the data attribute of the `select`, not the `option`. Use `$("#type-picker option:selected")`.

```
$('#type-picker').on('change', function (e) {
  var filter =  $("#type-picker option:selected").data("filter");
  console.log(filter);
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/zdng9s5o/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the selected `<option>` inside the `<select>`. `this` keyword references the `<select>`

Here's how you can do it without jQuery

```js
$('#type-picker').on('change', function (e) {
  var filter = this.children[this.selectedIndex].dataset.filter
  
  // this would also work
  //var filter = this.selectedOptions[0].dataset.filter
  
  console.log(filter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker" id="type-picker" data-width="100%" >
  <option data-filter="na" >Select From The List</option>
  <option data-filter="*">Display ALl</option>
  <option data-filter=".type1">Relish</option>
  <option data-filter=".type2">Relish</option>
  <option data-filter=".type3">Relish</option>
</select>
```