# JQuery Get Value from Select Option not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I dont know why my jquery code does not works to get value from select option.

I have created a function where when I click on "Add New Row" button then it will create a new row to my table.

Here's my JS code to add new row

```js
$(".tambah_sofa").on('click',function(){
    html = '<tr id="row_'+i+'">';
    html += '<td><button type="button" id="delete-button" data-row-delete="row_'+i+'">X</button></td>';
    html += '<td><select name="sofa[]" id="sofa"> <option value="'+sofa_rumah+'">Sofa rumah</option><option value="'+sofa_pejabat+'">Sofa Pejabat</option><option>Sofa Kedai</option><option>Tilam Tak Bujang</option> </select> </td>';
    html += '<td>X</td>';
    html += '<td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_'+i+'" value="1" disabled="disabled"></td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    sidebar = '<tr id="row_'+i+'">';
    sidebar += '<td><input style="width:50%;" type="text" id="price_sofa" value="" disabled="disabled"></td>';
    sidebar += '</tr>';
    $('#table_item').append(html);
    $('#table_sidebar').append(sidebar);
    i++;
});
```

Below is my code to get select option values into textbox :

```js
    $('#sofa').on('change', function () {
    $('#price_sofa').val(this.value);
    }).trigger('change');
```

I try to follow this JSfiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/JwB6z/2/

The code is working but when I try implement to my "add new row" function, it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is because any new row is not being recognised. I think you should bind the change to body...

example:

```
$('body').on('change', '#sofa', function () {
```

Comment: @Lucretech glad to help

Answer (score 1):

you can always use this:

```
$('#sofa').on('change', function () {
$('#price_sofa').find(':selected').val();
}).trigger('change');
```

**EDIT:** The above one is used to get the value you entered if you want to add the text and not value you can always put

```
$('#price_sofa).find(':selected').text();
```

**EDIT2:** When you use `$('#price_sofa').val(this.value);` you are not taking the selected option and a you can see in the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JwB6z/2/) that you added they didn't use the function that you used.

Hope this helps

Comment: They are working fine when i not append the row table. The code not working when i use my JS code to append new row into table. I totally lost here...

Comment: always use the one I wrote for you, it's more successful than the one that you used. for more information kindly llook [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Comment: Thanks ! I learn something new today. The code you wrote for me really help me.