# How can I select the value of a selected option with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling to find the answer from the documentation.

```
.form-group                                                                                 
  label.col-md-3.control-label(for='industry') Industry                                     
  .col-md-9                                                                                 
    select#industries.form-control                                                          
           option(value='Please Select') Please Select                                           
           option(value='A') A                                              
           option(value='C') C                                            
           option(value='D') D                                          
           option(value='S') S                                                   
           option(value='E') E
```

If there is an easier solution with JavaScript, I'd welcome that too.

Comment: Have you tried `$('select option:selected').val()`?

Comment: Saved the day brother. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Get Selected Option From Dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Comment: Please search before you ask [Duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you use 'my-select' as id of the select, you can do

```
$('#my-select').val();
```

Otherwise with JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('#my-select').value;
```

Considering the selectors you wrote above, this should be your selector (but I need to see the HTML to be sure):

```
$('.form-group label.col-md-3.control-label[for="industry"] .col-md-9  select#industries.form-control')
```

although this should be fine as well:

```
$('select#industries')
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about getting the selected `option`. Just get the value of the `select`:

```js
$( "select" ).change(function () {
    // Just use the val() method on the select to get its current value
    $( "#output" ).text( $(this).val() );
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<p>Click your selection: </p>
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
<div>You selected: <span id="output"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for javascript solution, it could be done this way:
1.Select the dropdown  element
2.Extract value from options collection

```js
function test() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('industries');
  var val = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log('Value=' + val);
}
```

```html
<select id="industries">
        <option value='Please Select'>Please Select</option>  
        <option value='A'>A</option>  
        <option value='B'>B</option>                                 </select>   

<button class="btn btn-success" id="buttonCode" type="button" onclick="test()">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$('#industries').val();` in JQuery

Comment: Or how about just: `$('#industries').val();` instead?

Comment: @ScottMarcus about the _select_, I know that an ID should be unique. But working with people thaught me it's not always true for everybody. About the way to select there are dozens of ways for doing it: _$('select option:selected').val()_ will also work.

Comment: It's not a matter of what will work. `:selected` is redundant. It's more to type and actually performs slower than just getting the value. As for `id`s, saying that you wrote a more complicated selector to protect against invalid HTML is really just a band-aid. The real cure is to write valid HTML and then use the appropriate selectors for it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus approved. Thanks for explaining

Answer (score -1):

```js
$( "select" ).change(function () {
    // Previous answer: technically incorrect logic
    // var str = $( "select option:selected" ).text();
    // $( "div" ).text( str );

    $( "div" ).text( $(this).val() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
<div></div>
```

[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: Super overkill. You only need to get the `val()` of the `select`. No need to test for the selected option.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I appreciate you figured out the redundancy in my code. I have updated it :) Thank you.

Comment: Still not right. Form elements use the `val()` method to get their value and you are still querying for the `selected` `option`. That is not necessary. See my answer for correct way.

Comment: I tried executing using the `Run code snippet`. It worked well. Meanwhile, I will clear my confusion on `.val()` and `.text()`

Comment: It may have worked, but it's still overkill. HTML form elements have names and values. Always use `val()` to get their value. `text()` can be different than the actual value.

Comment: `.val()` only selects the first occurrence of `select` element. `.text()` selects all the selected elements.

Comment: Not quite. First, `.text()` is for non-form elements. If you look at the JQuery  documentation for it (http://api.jquery.com/text/), you will see a `<p>` element being used in the example. When it is used, it combines the text of all the elements in the JQuery wrapped set. `val()` is exclusively for form elements. `select` is a form element. Here's the documentation for it: http://api.jquery.com/val/. Here, `val()` will return the value of a form element. If that element can have multiple values, all the values from that single element are combined.  This goes to the nature of HTML forms.

Comment: The reason we need to distinguish between `text()` and `val()` is that some form elements can display some text but store a different value. Such is the case with `<option>` elements. Take this for example: `<option value='CT'>Connecticut</option>`. `CT` is the value and `Connecticut` is the text. `CT` is what gets submitted with the form and that's why we care about `value` and not text when it comes to form elements.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I appreciate you clarifying my concerns. I will make a note of it.

Comment: This was an overkill for sure (as you said earlier :p)

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I have kept the old logic in code comments for users to understand. I would appreciate if you make bring my answer back to `0 score` so that people learn from my mistake as well as read your helpful comments.