# Clone a form according to select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to clone a form according to the numeric value from the select option. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzhyg2s4/1/):

Html code:

```
<div class="travel_tour-info">
<h3>How many people are you booking for?
<select name="travellers" id="travellers">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7 well" id="passanger">
<span id="person-1"><h5>Passenger 1 Lead traveller</h5></span>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="title" class="control-label col-sm-3 required">Title</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<select name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
<option value="Mr.">Mr</option>
<option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
<option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
<option value="Miss">Miss</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="name" class="control-label col-sm-3 required">First name</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="text" name="f_name" class="form-control" id="fname-1" placeholder="Enter name">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="address" class="control-label col-sm-3">Middle name</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="text" name="m_name" class="form-control" id="mname-1" placeholder="Enter address">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="name" class="control-label col-sm-3 required">Last name</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="text" name="l_name" class="form-control" id="lname-1" placeholder="Enter name">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 required"> Date of Birth:</label>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4">
<select id="dob_month" class="form-control" name="dob_month-1">
<option value="">1</option>
<option value="">2</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
<!-- added div.col-xs-4 -->
<select id="dob_day" class="form-control" name="dob_day-1">
<option value="">1</option>
<option value="">2</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
<!-- added div.col-xs-4 -->
<select id="dob_year" class="form-control" name="dob_year-1">
<option value="">1</option>
<option value="">2</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
<label class="control-label col-sm-3 required">
 Gender
</label>
<label class="control-label col-sm-3">
<input name="gender-1" type="radio" value="M" /> Male
</label>
<label class="control-label col-sm-3 ">
<input name="gender-1" type="radio" value="F" /> Female
</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="email" class="control-label col-sm-3 required">Email</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="email" name="email-1" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="contact" class="control-label col-sm-3 required">Contact no.
</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="tel" class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact-1" placeholder="Contact no.">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="address1" class="control-label col-sm-3 required">Address 1</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="text" name="address1-1" class="form-control" id="address1">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="address2" class="control-label col-sm-3">Address 2</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="text" name="address2-1" class="form-control" id="address2">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="town" class="control-label col-sm-3 required">Suburb / Town</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="text" name="town-1" class="form-control" id="town">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="state" class="control-label col-sm-3 required">State / Province</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="text" name="state-1" class="form-control" id="state">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="postcpde" class="control-label col-sm-3 required">Postcode / Zip</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="text" name="post-1" class="form-control" id="postcpde">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#travellers').change(function() {
    var travellerSelected = $('#travellers option:selected').val();
    var travellerDisplayed = $('[id^="person1-"]:visible').length;
    var travellerRendered = $('[id^="person-"]').length;

    if (travellerSelected > travellerDisplayed) {

        for (var i=1;i<=travellerSelected;i++){
            var r=$('#travellers-'+i);
            if (r.length == 0) {

                var clone=$('#travellers-1').clone(); //clone
                clone.children('#person1 h5').text("Traveller "+i);
                //change ids appropriately
                setNewID(clone,i);
                clone.children('div').each(function() {
                    setNewID($(this),i);
                });
                $(clone).insertAfter($('#travellers-'+travellerRendered));

            }else {
                $(r).show();
            }
        }

    }
    else {
        for (var i=++travellerSelected;i<=travellerRendered;i++){
            $('#travellers-'+i).hide();
        }
    }

});
function setNewID(elem, i) {
    oldID=elem.attr('id');
    newId=oldID.substring(0,oldID.indexOf('-'))+"-"+i;
    elem.attr('id',newId);
 }
});
```

But I'm getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined` in my console. I've been trying to fix this error since few days. What wrong am I doing here ?
[image: Error]

Comment: you should declarate your variable oldID `var oldID=elem.attr('id');` also `var newId = .. `

Comment: Do you want to copy your selected option ? I think this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown

Comment: There is not any **#travellers-** id in your html.

Comment: @TienNguyen thank you for pointing out the fault in my code. I changed it. Now there is no error in js but the code is not working. I mean form is not being cloned.

Comment: You should edit your again.I will see your code.

Comment: @TienNguyen here is the updated fiddle link.

Comment: I can not see your link.

Comment: @TienNguyen here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/vzhyg2s4/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited your code, but it is hard to explain. You can see and improve your code. I hope it will help you.

In script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    $('#travellers').change(function () {
        var travellerSelected = $('#travellers option:selected').val();
        var travellerDisplayed = $('[id^="person-"]:visible').length;
        var travellerRendered = $('[id^="person-"]').length;
        if (travellerSelected > travellerDisplayed) {

            for (var i = 1; i <= travellerSelected; i++) {
                var r = $('#passanger-' + i);
                if (r.length == 0) {

                    var clone = $('#passanger-1').clone(); //clone
                    clone.children('#person-1')[0].innerHTML = "<h5>Traveller " + i + "<h5>";
                    //change ids appropriately
                    setNewID(clone, i);
                    //clone.children('div').each(function () {
                    //setNewID($(this), i);
                    //});
                    clone.find('div').each(function () {
                        setNewID($(this), i);
                    });
                    clone.insertAfter($('#passanger-' + travellerRendered));

                } else {
                    $(r).show();
                }
            }

        } else {
            for (var i = ++travellerSelected; i <= travellerRendered; i++) {
                $('#passanger-' + i).hide();
            }
        }
    });

});

function setNewID(elem, i) {
    if (typeof elem.attr('id') === "undefined") {
        return;
    }
    oldID = elem.attr('id');
    newId = oldID.substring(0, oldID.indexOf('-')) + "-" + i;
    elem.attr('id', newId);
}
</script>
```

In Html

```
<div class="travel_tour-info">
  <h3>How many people are you booking for?
        <select name="travellers" id="travellers">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>                                        
        </select>
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7 well" id="passanger">
<div id="passanger-1">
  <span id="person-1"><h5>Passenger 1 Lead traveller</h5></span>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title" class="control-label col-sm-3 required">Title</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <select name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
        <option value="Mr.">Mr</option>
        <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
        <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label col-sm-3 required">First name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="f_name" class="form-control" id="fname-1" placeholder="Enter name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="address" class="control-label col-sm-3">Middle name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="m_name" class="form-control" id="mname-1" placeholder="Enter address">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label col-sm-3 required">Last name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="l_name" class="form-control" id="lname-1" placeholder="Enter name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 required"> Date of Birth:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- added div.row -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <!-- added div.col-xs-4 -->
          <select id="dob_month" class="form-control" name="dob_month-1">
            <option value="">1</option>
            <option value="">2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <!-- added div.col-xs-4 -->
          <select id="dob_day" class="form-control" name="dob_day-1">
            <option value="">1</option>
            <option value="">2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <!-- added div.col-xs-4 -->
          <select id="dob_year" class="form-control" name="dob_year-1">
            <option value="">1</option>
            <option value="">2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3 required">
      Gender
    </label>
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3">
      <input name="gender-1" type="radio" value="M" /> Male
    </label>
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3 ">
      <input name="gender-1" type="radio" value="F" /> Female
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="control-label col-sm-3 required">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="email" name="email-1" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="contact" class="control-label col-sm-3 required">Contact no.</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact-1" placeholder="Contact no.">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="address1" class="control-label col-sm-3 required">Address 1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="address1-1" class="form-control" id="address1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="address2" class="control-label col-sm-3">Address 2</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="address2-1" class="form-control" id="address2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="town" class="control-label col-sm-3 required">Suburb / Town</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="town-1" class="form-control" id="town">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="state" class="control-label col-sm-3 required">State / Province</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="state-1" class="form-control" id="state">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="postcpde" class="control-label col-sm-3 required">Postcode / Zip</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="post-1" class="form-control" id="postcpde">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Seems like I had missed a lot of chunk in the code.