# Get the value of dropdown option when mouseover using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a drop down list in html page and i need to get the value of the mouse-over item using j Query, please advise

my dropdown code

```
<select name="select2" id="sub_groups" class="form-control input-md" onchange="getval(this);" >
                                                     <option data-group='SHOW' value="0" selected="selected">Select Turbine Type</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V1">V39/ V42/ V44/ V47</option>
                                                      <!--option data-group='1' value="V2">V42-600KW</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V3">V44-600KW</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V4">V47-660KW</option-->
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V5">V52-850KW</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V6">V66-1.65MW/ 1.75MW</option>
                                                      <!--option data-group='1' value="V7">V66-1.75MW</option-->
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V8">V80-V90 1.8-2.0MW, MK1-5</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V9">V80-V90 1.8-2.0MW, MK5.1,6-7</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V10">V80-V90 1.8-2.0MW, MK8</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V11">V82-1.65MW</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V12">V90-3MW</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V14">V100 1.8-2.0MW, MK7</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V15">V100 2.0MW, MK9</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V16">V100 2.0MW, MK10</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V18">V110-2.0MW, Mk10, 10B</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V17">V105-3.3/3.45MW, MK2C</option>   
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V19">V112-3.0 MW, Mk0,0E,1A,1B</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V20">V112-3.3/3.45MW, MK2A-2C</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V21">V117-3.3/3.45MW, MK2A-2C</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V22">V126-3.3/3.45MW, MK2A-2C</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V23">NM52 / NM64(950KW, 1MW) </option>
                                                      <!--option data-group='1' value="V24">NM54-950KW</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V25">NM54-1MW</option-->

                                                    </select>
```

and my jquery

```
$("#sub_groups").hover(function() {
alert("hello");
```

});

When i mouse over on any of the dropdown item i should get the values 
[image]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: show your dropdown code?

Comment: i have added my code please advise

Comment: @ponraj89 check with my answer

Answer (score 1):

It will be something like this:

```js
$('#sub_groups').mousemove(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select2" id="sub_groups" class="form-control input-md" onchange="getval(this);">
                                                     <option data-group='SHOW' value="0" selected="selected">Select Turbine Type</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V1">V39/ V42/ V44/ V47</option>
                                                      <!--option data-group='1' value="V2">V42-600KW</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V3">V44-600KW</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V4">V47-660KW</option-->
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V5">V52-850KW</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V6">V66-1.65MW/ 1.75MW</option>
                                                      <!--option data-group='1' value="V7">V66-1.75MW</option-->
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V8">V80-V90 1.8-2.0MW, MK1-5</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V9">V80-V90 1.8-2.0MW, MK5.1,6-7</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V10">V80-V90 1.8-2.0MW, MK8</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V11">V82-1.65MW</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V12">V90-3MW</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V14">V100 1.8-2.0MW, MK7</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V15">V100 2.0MW, MK9</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V16">V100 2.0MW, MK10</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V18">V110-2.0MW, Mk10, 10B</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V17">V105-3.3/3.45MW, MK2C</option>   
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V19">V112-3.0 MW, Mk0,0E,1A,1B</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V20">V112-3.3/3.45MW, MK2A-2C</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V21">V117-3.3/3.45MW, MK2A-2C</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V22">V126-3.3/3.45MW, MK2A-2C</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V23">NM52 / NM64(950KW, 1MW) </option>
                                                      <!--option data-group='1' value="V24">NM54-950KW</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V25">NM54-1MW</option-->

                                                    </select>
```

```
$('#sub_groups').mousemove(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
 });
```

You use the [mouse move event](https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) and [get the value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19609269/20126) inside

Comment: Thanks for the advise, i already tried and i am getting the values only on mouse release. i need it on the mouse over

Comment: did you check my code snippet?, i see it is working there, or do you want something else to happen?

Comment: on getting the value through mouseover i am going to highlight few other items in the same list ..but since i am getting the values only after mouse release i am not able to highlight other related things

Comment: how you will highlight them?

Comment: by set option as selected

Answer (score 0):

I think its a dynamically appended element.so use with `on()`

```js
$(document).on('mouseover','#sub_groups',function() {
  console.log($(this).val())

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select2" id="sub_groups" class="form-control input-md" onchange="getval(this);">
                                                     <option data-group='SHOW' value="0" selected="selected">Select Turbine Type</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V1">V39/ V42/ V44/ V47</option>
                                                      <!--option data-group='1' value="V2">V42-600KW</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V3">V44-600KW</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V4">V47-660KW</option-->
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V5">V52-850KW</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V6">V66-1.65MW/ 1.75MW</option>
                                                      <!--option data-group='1' value="V7">V66-1.75MW</option-->
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V8">V80-V90 1.8-2.0MW, MK1-5</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V9">V80-V90 1.8-2.0MW, MK5.1,6-7</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V10">V80-V90 1.8-2.0MW, MK8</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V11">V82-1.65MW</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V12">V90-3MW</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V14">V100 1.8-2.0MW, MK7</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V15">V100 2.0MW, MK9</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V16">V100 2.0MW, MK10</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V18">V110-2.0MW, Mk10, 10B</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V17">V105-3.3/3.45MW, MK2C</option>   
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V19">V112-3.0 MW, Mk0,0E,1A,1B</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V20">V112-3.3/3.45MW, MK2A-2C</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V21">V117-3.3/3.45MW, MK2A-2C</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V22">V126-3.3/3.45MW, MK2A-2C</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V23">NM52 / NM64(950KW, 1MW) </option>
                                                      <!--option data-group='1' value="V24">NM54-950KW</option>
                                                      <option data-group='1' value="V25">NM54-1MW</option-->

                                                    </select>
```

Comment: Thanks @prasad but again struck up with the same thing

Comment: what is the struck?

Comment: on mouse over it is not giving the value