# how can check selected item in asp.net drop down list?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm new in asp.net. i wrote script for checking the value of asp.net drop down list(below code):

```
     <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        $('#<%=offermessage.ClientID%>').on('change', function () {
            var a = $(this).val();

         if (a == 9) {
             $('#dealer_name').fadeIn();
             $('#vin_number').fadeOut();

         }
         if (a == 10) {
             $('#dealer_name').fadeIn();
             $('#vin_number').fadeIn();
         }
         if (a == 11) {
             $('#vin_number').fadeIn();
             $('#dealer_name').fadeOut();
         }
         if (a == 12) {
             $('#dealer_name').fadeOut();
             $('#vin_number').fadeOut();
         }
         if (a == 13) {
             alert("لطفا موضوع پیشنهاد و شکایت را انتخاب نمایید.")
         }
     });

 });
</script>
```

now i need to write an script that checked the value when i want to submit the form.below script written and function return in submit button .

```
     <script>
    function subjectvalidate(offermessage) {
        $('#<%=offermessage.ClientID%>').on('select', function () {
            var a = $(this).val();
            if (a == 13) {
                alert("لطفا موضوع پیشنهاد و شکایت را انتخاب نمایید.")
                return false;
            }
        }
        )};
</script>
```

but it's not work .any body can help me ??? thanks

Comment: why do you add a handler for `select` event? it's not going to run your code until the event happen.

Comment: @derloopkat how i can get value of drop down for "a" variable??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10659117/2516718

Comment: Also `offermessage` is not being used in that function since ClientID property is evaluated at server side, then when script runs at client side it becomes a literal like myId hardcoded in $('#myId')

Comment: @derloopkat i did'nt get you point in comment about offermessage and clientid