# get value of dynamic drop down in j query

Tags: jquery

```
return '<select name="AMStatus" onchange="changeValueuserid(this)" id="optbox-'+index2+'" class=\"opcodes\"><option value="3">Authorize</option><option value="14">Reject</option></select>';
```

I want to get option value to the variable.I using jQuery.above code also in my js file.

Comment: Please include all relevant code and where/why it don't work

Comment: Are you looking something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown?

Comment: In your onchange function replace 'this' with 'this.value'

Comment: I found the answer..I catch those values in my onchange event function...thankyou guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.test').each(function()
    {

          {      

        var $val = $("option:selected",this).text();
      alert($val);
     }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="test">      
      <option>
        Number 1
      </option>
      <option>
        Number 2
      </option>
      <option>
        Number 4
      </option>      
   </select>
```

This is a quick example.

Comment: I found the answer..I catch those values in my onchange event function...thank you guys...