# How to get value of selected dropdown value on button click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap with jquery to create a dynamic table consisting dropdown menu and button.
I want to get value of dropdown menu selected in jquery on button click.

Below is my code

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
  {% for item in items %}
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Select
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="options" onchange="selectFromDropDown(this.value)">
            <li><a id="weekly" selected>Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a id="biweekly">Option 2</a></li>
            <li><a id="monthly">Option 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" >
          <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-xs btn-block" id="update">
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And below is the jquery

```
$('#update').click(function(){
  alert($('#options option:selected').html())
});
```

When I run above code it returns "undefined".

Comment: You are using list instead of <select>. You should use your script like this. `$("#options .selected").text()`

Comment: Maybe make it a `<select>` rather than a `<ul>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Get Selected Option From Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Comment: try $('#options').find('a[selected]').html()

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `select` from control then no worry to code for it. Just do a little change in your code.

```
$('#update').click(function(){
  alert($('#options').val());
});
```

Or if you are using `ul, li` then change your jquery code like this.

```
$('#update').click(function(){
  alert($('#options .selected').text())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```js
$('#update').on('click', function () {
    alert($('#options').find('[selected]').html());
});
```

Firstly I made use of the `on` function, since the `click` function will trigger an actual click (IIRC).

Then I make use of the CSS selected `[selected]` which is the [attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp); combined with `find` (which searches children for the selector), it should work.

---

All that said and done, there is no way of changing the *selected* attribute through clicking the on the dropdown - unless you use JavaScript - because only `options` use the selected attribute.

```
$('#options a').on('click', function () {
    $('#options a').removeAttr('selected');
    $(this).attr('selected', true);
});
```

The above code is a workaround that will allow your drop down to work correctly with my above code.
Effectively, all it is doing is removing the selected attribute from *all* `#option a` elements, and then gives it to the one that was clicked on.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7rwb0p4a/)
<sub>I used JSFiddle rather than a snippet for brevity, since this answer is already quite long as it is and prevents repeating the question askers code...</sub>

Answer (score 0):

May b you are looking for this. if it's dropdown

```
$('#update').click(function(){
 alert($('#options').find(":selected").text());
});
```

if its unordered list you can use this

```
$('#update').click(function(){
 alert($('#options > li > a:selected').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery search is not correct inside the click event. You are looking for option tag inside #option identifier and your html refers to a unordered list  tag. Make selected element search according to your html

```
$('#update').click(function(){
  alert($('#options > li > a:selected').html())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your `for` loop is duplicating element `id`s. The `id` attribute **must** be unique, otherwise any filtering operation, including attaching listeners, will return the first element only and your actions won't work. I've targeted a different selector in my example. You *might* get away with it by using duplicates in your dropdowns "`options`" as standins for `value` as long as you don't target them directly.

Then, since there are multiple rows, you'll have to find in which one the dropdown is so you can then get the corresponding value. You can do this by using `closest` and `find`.

Also, if you have many rows, you should consider using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) too, so you have less listeners attached. I've used this solution.

Now, since the dropdown isn't a real `select`, it won't respond to `change` events, so I provided my own selection function using delegates too. Since it's an anchor you can't use the `:selected` pseudoselector, you have to check for the attribute being present.

```js
$('table').on('click', '.btn-update', function(evt) {
  $clicked = $(this).closest('tr').find('.dropdown-menu a[selected]')
  console.log($clicked.text())
  // You can get the emulated 'value' too
  console.log($clicked.attr('id'))
  // Cancel the 'button' default action
  evt.preventDefault()
});

$('table').on('click', '.dropdown-menu', function(evt) {
  // Find the 'selected' anchor inside this dropdown and remove the attribute
  $(evt.currentTarget).find('a[selected]').removeAttr('selected')
  // Add the attribute to the clicked one
  $(evt.target).attr('selected', true)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Select
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="options">
            <li><a id="weekly">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a id="biweekly" selected>Option 2</a></li>
            <li><a id="monthly">Option 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
          <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-xs btn-block btn-update" id="update">
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Select
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="options">
            <li><a id="weekly" selected>Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a id="biweekly">Option 2</a></li>
            <li><a id="monthly">Option 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
          <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-xs btn-block btn-update" id="update">
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```