# How to detect which option has been chosen in "Select" dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I am using a vanilla "select" dropdown so the user can select one of the options. I need to know what option has been selected so I can update another column for example : 
if the user selected "Very good", the "Score" column will update to 5/5.

I have tried giving ids and changing the "value" attribute of the different options, but it does not solve the problem that i do not know which one is selected.

Here is the dropdown I am using

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <select>
    <option value="very bad">very bad</option>
    <option value="bad">bad</option>
    <option value="normal">normal</option>
    <option value="good">good</option>
    <option value="very good">very good</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I expect the HTML element "option" to change if it is selected but even when inspecting, I cannot see a difference. Note that the "value" attribute is always equal to the inner Text if that can help.
I believe I am not using Jquery.

Comment: what is `Score` column? and when you select an option, the HTML does change. That `option` takes an attribute `selected`

Comment: You're quite close to the answer, you have to do those on the select element, the options doesn't become selected, the select get the value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Get Selected Option From Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Comment: where is your form

Comment: giri : I am not using a form, I am using a dropdown. Lamonde & quirimmo : where can we see if the column takes the attribute `selected` ? When inspecting, I cannot see it change, also, I am fairly new to Rails and Javascript so I am unsure of what JQuery is..

Comment: document.querySelector(".dropdown select").value; get you the value and to see the change, you can add an event listener: document.addEventListener('change', function(){ /* Action here*/ });

Answer (score 0):

When selected, an item from a dropdown list such as the one I provided takes the attribute `select`. For reasons I do not know, this change is not visible while using "inspect" in the browser.

To find selected element, you have to use `document.querySelector("select").value)`.

There is no need to play around with the `id` or the `value` attribute.