# How do you find the value of the selected option in a dropdown list using javascript and html when you are using <option id>?

Tags: javascript

I am currently using a play code environment, and I need to find the value of the id of the option selected.

```js
function func1() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <select id="selectFrom" class="selectOption inputOption" onchange="onChangeUnit();">
    <option value="1">Centimeters (cm)</option>
    <option value="2">Inches (in)</option>
    <option value="3">Kilometers (km)
    </option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Where is `class="dropdown-content"` in your HTML?

Comment: `openDropdown.value` is the value of the selected option.

Comment: The classes and IDs in your JavaScript don't have anything to do with the classes and IDs in the HTML.

Comment: You need to find the ID of the selected option - none of your options have IDs, did you mean the *value*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Get Selected Option From Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)