# How to collect selected dropdown text with Javascript DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4 example html below, how can I extract the text from selected dropdown menu option with JS DOM or Jquery?

```
<select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

I know that I can fetch the value but not the text within `<option></option>` with something like this:

```
$("#inputGroupSelect01").change(function (){

    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Let's assume the `value` is an ID and the text is a column in my database. I need to fetch this information to submit a PUT request with the ID and the text. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Get Selected Option From Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add **option:selected** to your ID in jQuery:

```
$("#inputGroupSelect01").change(function (){
    alert($("#inputGroupSelect01 option:selected").text())
});
```