# How to pass an ajax selected dependent dropdown option to mysql database in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I have two dependent dropdown box in a form. From them, I will use one dependent dropdown box's selected option to update a column's fields in a table in the DB. But, I really can't figure out, how exactly can I fetch the selected option from this dependent dropdown box and pass it to the database after I press the submit button of the form.

I am using ajax to do this task. I've followed some tutorials, but they only show, how to add options dynamically in a dependent dropdown box without any submit button. But, I need to pass a dependent dropdown option's value which I've selected from the dropdown box, to DB to update a column after pressing the submit button.

Here's my controller:

```
public function fetch_session() {


                if($this->input->post('subject'))
                {
                    echo $this->Result_Model->fetch_session($this->input->post('subject'));
                }

                if($this->input->post('syllabus'))
                {
                    echo  $this->Result_Model->fetch_syllabus($this->input->post('syllabus'));
                } 

            }
```

Here's my Model:

```
public function fetch_session($subject) {
                $this->db->select('session');
                $this->db->group_by('session');
                $this->db->from('student');
                $this->db->where('subject',$subject);
                $query = $this->db->get();

             $output = '<option value="">Select Session</option>';
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
  $output .= '<option value="'.$row->subject.'">'.$row->session.'</option>'; 
              }
              return $output;
             }


        public function fetch_syllabus($syllabus) {
            $this->db->select('profile');
            $this->db->group_by('profile');
            $this->db->from('syllabus');
            $this->db->where('subject',$syllabus);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $output = '<option value="">Select Syllabus</option>';
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
  $output .= '<option value="'.$row->subject.'">'.$row->profile.'</option>';
              }
              return $output;
        }
```

Here's my View:

```
<body>
    <div class = "container" align = "center">
    <br><br>

    <?php echo form_open('Result_Controller/fetch_session'); ?> 

    <label>Subject</label>

    <select class="col-sm-2 custom-select custom-select-sm" 
        name="subjects" id="subjects">
    <option value = "">Select Subject</option>
    <option value = "CSE">CSE</option>
        <option value = "Fisheries">Fisheries</option>
        <option value = "Agriculture">Agriculture</option>
    <option value = "NFS">NFS</option>
        </select>                   
        <br><br>

  <label>Session</label>
   <select class="col-sm-2 custom-select custom-select-sm" name="session" id="session">
    <option value="">Select Session</option>  
  </select>
    <br><br>

      <label>Syllabus</label>
      <select class="col-sm-2 custom-select custom-select-sm" name="syllabus" id="syllabus">
      <option value="">Select Syllabus</option> 
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
       </form>
</div>

<script src = "<?php echo base_url('/js/jquery-3.js') ?>"></script>
<script src = "<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') ?>"></script>

</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#subjects').change(function() {
        var subject = $('#subjects').val();

        if(subject != '')
        {
            $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url();?>/Result_Controller/fetch_session",
    method: "POST",
    data:{subject:subject},
    success:function(data)
    {                
            $('#session').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    if(subject != '')
    {
         $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url();>/Result_Controller/fetch_session",
        method: "POST",
        data:{syllabus:subject},
        success:function(data)
        {
        $('#syllabus').html(data);
          }
        });
            } 
    });
});
</script>
```

I've done as far as I could understand and may be wasted my last 10 hours. I know it's an incomplete and even may be a wrong code . But I need to know, what I should do further. I'm working in CI for a while but I'm completely new in Ajax. So, if anyone thinks that, I may need to read some resource first, please share some. I've already read a bunch of articles regarding this problem but nothing has helped much till now.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

In your view you should remove this part as you trigger the ajax post from your script:

`<?php echo form_open('Result_Controller/fetch_session'); ?>  </form`

And then in your script change your submit button to a `<input type="button id="submitbtn" value="Submit">` 
and since you want to trigger your update after pressing submit button change the event that holds the ajax post to click event of the `submitbtn` button.

Comment: Well, the options of first dropdown box(subject) can be easily posted to controller and I can print it in controller too, as the options are inserted in static way. But, I can't post the options of dependent dropdown box to the controller. They are dynamically fetched from the database, not statically. Can you just tell me, how can I just print the selected option from the dependent dropdown box in the controller? In this case, it's the session and syllabus box.

Comment: you can do `$('#optionID :selected').text()` to get the selected value from your select component.

Comment: Sorry but I really can't get this thing inside my head. Can you please give some code snippet?

Comment: You can check this link on how to get the selected option in a dropdown using jquery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown

Comment: Oh man!! I've finally made it work. The solution was not that tough. But as I'm new in ajax, it was a bit tough for me to find the problem. And your given link has really helped me. Many many thanks to you. :-D

Comment: @Drowning_Prince no worries glad that I helped.

Comment: Keith bro, I'm facing a new problem similar to this. This time, I've a dependent dropdown box in another page. What I need to do is, I've to fetch value from my current page's dependent dropdown box and send that value to that another page when I click 'Submit'. And when I click Submit, I also will be redirected to that another page. Now the other page's dependent dropdown box will use this fetched value as condition and get its own options from database.

Comment: I can simply post data from ajax using ` $('#submitbtn').click(function() `
But I when I redirect to that page, I can't find the values that I just posted from ajax while clicking 'Submit'. And for this, the other page's dropdown box doesn't fetch any value from database. What is the reason?

Comment: I can help you with that but it is much better if you post that problem properly here in SO they might have much better answers than I have.