# how to copy selected value in a drop down list

Tags: jquery, materialize

I have a piece of code i am trying to get the selected value and return it

```
<div class="language-box">
        <div id=mylist class="language-choice">
        <#if realm.internationalizationEnabled  && locale.supported?size gt 1>
            <ul id = "dropdown" class = "dropdown-content">
                <#list locale.supported as l>
                   <li><a href = "${l.url}" id="selected">${l.label}<span class = "badge"></span></a></li>
                </#list>
            </ul>
            <a class = "btn dropdown-button" style="background-color: #f5b71b;" data-activates = "dropdown"><p id="lang"></p><i class = "mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down right"></i></a>
        </#if>
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                          function changelabel() {
                              console.log("***" + $('#selected :selected').text())
                          }
                        document.getElementById("lang").innerHTML = changelabel();
                    </script>

        </div>
    </div>
```

But currently i have undefined, im not sure if i have placed the id in the wrong place or not, this is jquery and materialcss

below is the whole page as generated

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">

        <title>Zaloguj się do Auto-konto-Realm</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/auth/resources/7zry3/login/mytheme/img/favicon.ico"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
                <link href="/auth/resources/7zry3/login/mytheme/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body class="">
    <div class="language-box">
        <div id=mylist class="language-choice">
            <ul id = "dropdown" class = "dropdown-content">
                   <li><a href = "/auth/realms/Auto-konto-Realm/login-actions/authenticate?client_id=autokonto&amp;tab_id=70-Y23dT6jg&amp;execution=1ac9d9f6-6fc0-4cd7-a080-ed4aaaa33b46&amp;kc_locale=en" id="selected">Angielski<span class = "badge"></span></a></li>
                   <li><a href = "/auth/realms/Auto-konto-Realm/login-actions/authenticate?client_id=autokonto&amp;tab_id=70-Y23dT6jg&amp;execution=1ac9d9f6-6fc0-4cd7-a080-ed4aaaa33b46&amp;kc_locale=pl" id="selected">Polski<span class = "badge"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class = "btn dropdown-button" style="background-color: #f5b71b;" data-activates = "dropdown"><p id="lang"></p><i class = "mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down right"></i></a>
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                          function changelabel() {
                              console.log("***" + $('#selected :selected').text())
                          }
                        document.getElementById("lang").innerHTML = changelabel();
                    </script>

        </div>
    </div>
      <div class="kc-logo-text">
        <div class="logos">
        </div>
       </div>
     <div class=" container">
        <div id="kc-header" class="">
            <div id="kc-header-wrapper"
                 class="">Auto-konto-Realm</div>
        </div>
        <div class="valign-wrapper row center">
            <div class="">
            </div>
            <div id="kc-content" class="col card s12 pull-s0 m11 pull-m0 l4 pull-l4">
                <div id="kc-content-wrapper" class="xyz1">
                    <div class="">
        <div id="kc-form" >
            <div id="kc-form-wrapper" >
                    <div style="height: 50px; width: 50px;"></div>
                    <form id="kc-form-login"
                          onsubmit="login.disabled = true; return true;"
                          action="http://localhost:8181/auth/realms/Auto-konto-Realm/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=XlcnnWczwxBUCo_HHm-YZ8uFbpX_qrxpr1PCyI5fBac&amp;execution=1ac9d9f6-6fc0-4cd7-a080-ed4aaaa33b46&amp;client_id=autokonto&amp;tab_id=70-Y23dT6jg"
                          method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <label for="username">Nazwa użytkownika lub e-mail (login)</label>

                                    <input tabindex="1"
                                           id="username"
                                           name="username"
                                           value=""
                                           type="text"
                                           minlength="4"
                                           autofocus
                                           autocomplete="off"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <input tabindex="2"
                                       id="password"
                                       type="password"
                                       name="password"
                                       minlength="4"
                                       autocomplete="off">
                                <label for="password">Hasło</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class=" ">
                                <div id="kc-form-options">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                    <input tabindex="3"
                                                           id="rememberMe"
                                                           name="rememberMe"
                                                           type="checkbox"> Zapamiętaj mnie
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div id="kc-form-buttons" class=" col s12">
                                <button tabindex="4"
                                        class="waves-effect waves-light btn"
                                        name="login"
                                        id="kc-login"
                                        type="submit">Logowanie
                                </button>
                                    <div class="">
                                        <button type="button" tabindex="5"
                                                class="waves-effect waves-light btn darken-2"
                                                onclick="location.href='/auth/realms/Auto-konto-Realm/login-actions/registration?client_id=autokonto&amp;tab_id=70-Y23dT6jg';">Rejestracja</button>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>

                            <div id="kc-info" class="">
                                <div id="kc-info-wrapper" class="">
        <div class="">
                <button tabindex="5"
                        class="waves-effect waves-light btn darken"
                        onclick="location.href='/auth/realms/Auto-konto-Realm/login-actions/reset-credentials?client_id=autokonto&amp;tab_id=70-Y23dT6jg';">Nie pamiętasz hasła?</button>
        </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you mean the whole page ?@quantumPuter

Comment: In HTML, you can't use an id more than once.

Comment: no, my piece of code uses id = "selected" once and then in javascript it calls the id,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You can set value of `lang` element by simply getting `a:first` value and then asssign that value using  `.text()`. Also , if you want to change value of `lang` on click of `a` tag you can write `click` event handler for same and use `$("#lang").text($(this).text())` to set selected `li a` value.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#lang").text($("#dropdown > li a:first").text()) //get first li a > text by default
//on click of a tag
$("#dropdown > li a").on("click", function() {
  //get text and add new value under lang
  $("#lang").text($(this).text())

})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js">
</script>

<div class="language-box">
  <div id=mylist class="language-choice">

    <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="#">Angielski<span class = "badge"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Polski<span class = "badge"></span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <a class="btn dropdown-button" style="background-color: #f5b71b;width:150px;height:50px;" data-activates="dropdown">
      <p id="lang"></p><i class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down right"></i></a>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this part $("#lang").text($("#dropdown > li a:first").text()) //get first li a > text by default
//on click of a tag
$("#dropdown > li a").on("click", function() {
  //get text and add new value under lang
  $("#lang").text($(this).text())

})  should be added within a <script tag or not  ? and thank you for answering