# How to get the text of selected option instead of value

Tags: html, jquery, forms, web

Here's the body of my html:

```
  <form class="p-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Full Name</label>
                <input id="inputName" type="text" oninput="Update(this.value, 'namec')" 
  class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Robert">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Contact Number</label>
                    <input id="inputNumber" type="text" oninput="Update(this.value, 
   'numberc')" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="09*********">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input id="inputEmail" type="email" oninput="Update(this.value, 'emailc')" 
    class="form-control"
                        placeholder="email@gmail.com">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Full Address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="1234 Main St"
                    oninput="Update(this.value, 'addressc')">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Mode of Payment</label>
                    <select id="inputMOP" class="form-control" oninput="Update(this.value, 'mopc')">
                        <option selected>Select Payment</option>
                        <option>GCash</option>
                        <option>Bank Payment</option>
                        <option>Cash On Delivery</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Shipping Option</label>
                    <select id="inputMOD" class="form-control" oninput="Update(this.value, 
   'modc')">
                        <option selected>Select Delivery</option>
                        <option>Standard Delivery</option>
                        <option>J&T Express</option>
                        <option>Ninjavan Express</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                    <label>Item Name</label>
                    <select id="inputItem" class="itemInput form-control" 
     oninput="Update(this.value, 'itemc')">
                        <option selected>Select Item</option>
                        <option value="155.00">Hygienix Alcohol 1L</option>
                        <option value="180.00">Protect Plus Alcohol 1 Gal</option>
                        <option value="215.00">Guardian Alcohol 1 Gal</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label>Quantity</label>
                    <input id="inputQuantity" type="text" oninput="Update(this.value, 
   'quantityc')"
                        class="itemQuantity form-control" placeholder="0"><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <h6 class="mt-2">Total Price: ₱ </h6>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <input id="itemPrice" type="text" oninput="Update(this.value, 'pricec')" 
    class="form-control" placeholder="0" readonly>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <button id="placeOrder" class="btn btn-primary btn-block float- 
   right">Place Order</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Jquery to calculate the total price:

```
     <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select.itemInput').on('change', function () {
            $('.itemQuantity').text($('#inputQuantity').val(0));

            $('.itemQuantity').on('change', function () {
                $('#itemPrice').val(
                    $('#inputItem').val() * $('#inputQuantity').val() + ".00"
                );

            });
        });

    });
  </script>
```

Variable declaration to add to the database:

```
     var cName = $('#inputName').val();
    var cNumber = $('#inputNumber').val();
    var cEmail = $('#inputEmail').val();
    var cAddress = $('#inputAddress').val();
    var cMop = $('#inputMop').val();
    var cMod = $('#inputMod').val();
    var cItem = $('#inputItem').find(":selected").text();
    var cQuantity = $('#inputQuantity').val();
    var cPrice = $('#itemPrice').val();
```

The problem is that I cant get the text of the selected option from the #inputItem. It only gets the value from the option. Another thing, I can't also get the total price which is under the ID of #itemPrice.

How can I get the text instead of value of #inputItem? Also, the value of #itemPrice?

EDIT:

Finally solved it!! But I have a new problem, I cant add data with a "@gmail.com" but it works when it does not have it. How can I do add data with "@email.com"?

Comment: `$('#inputItem').find(":selected").text()` [will](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrn8wfx3/) [give](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10659117/2181514) you the selected text.  Are you calling it before the text has been selected?  Are there multiple `id=inputItem` elements?  Please [edit] your question to include a complete, working snippet to demonstrate the issue.  See [mcve].

Comment: (possibly) off topic: Note that you have nested events.  This is generally not a good idea.   Your .itemQuantity change event won't fire until after you've made an itemInput change and if you change itemInput multiple times, you'll get multiple itemQuantity event handlers which may cause conflicts (probably won't in this case, but running `$("#itemPrice").val` 20 times is still not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following script for the desired results. Also if you don't have any function to call onChange, kindly remove those from your input fields, from html. They will keep on throwing errors in console.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.itemInput').on('change', function () {

    // tempItemName stores the selected item name
    var tempItemName = $('.itemInput option:selected').text();
    totalPriceCalc();

  });

  $('.itemQuantity').on('change', function(){
    totalPriceCalc();
  });

  function totalPriceCalc () {
    var tempInputQty = $('#inputQuantity').val();
    var tempItemPrice = $('#inputItem option:selected').val();
    var tempTotalCost = (tempInputQty * tempItemPrice) + '.00';
    $('#itemPrice').val(tempTotalCost);
  }

});
```

Comment: I've done this and put it before the declaration of var to add to database and it works!! Thank you so much~ Another problem appeared tho. I cant add my data to firebase when the email includes the "@gmail.com" but works when it does not have it. How can I add my data with the "@gmail.com" ?

Comment: I wish I could help with that, but don't have much idea about that. May be the community can help!! Cheers