# How do get the result from jQuery change method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This shouldn't be so difficult... A little rusty with Javascript and jQuery and I think I'm missing something obvious.

Code sample. Abbreviated DOM

```
<select data-drupal-selector="edit-country-code-country" id="edit-country-code-country" name="country_code[country]"
    class="form-select is-empty">
    <option value="" selected="selected">- None -</option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
    <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
</select>
```

Code from script (doesn't work)

```
$('select[id^="edit-country-code-country"]').on('change', () => {
      const $target = $('#opt-in-wrapper');
      const countryNames = drupalSettings.r1;
      const $countrySelected = $('#select2-edit-country-code-country-container').attr('title');

      const countryCode = this.value;
      const test1 = $(this).value;
      const this2 = $(this).change;
      const this3 = $(this).data();

      const elem = $(this);
      const test5 = elem.value;
      const test6 = elem.value();
```

What I don't understand is why `this.value` returns undefined in the script but works as I would expect in the debug console

Debug results screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Get Selected Option From Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you used arrow function in the scope of checkCountryChange, I think `this` belong to upper scope inside it so Replace arrow function with regular function  to fix the issue.

```js
$('#edit-country-code-country').on('change', function(){
    alert(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <select data-drupal-selector="edit-country-code-country" id="edit-country-code-country" name="country_code[country]"
        class="form-select is-empty">
        <option value="" selected="selected">- None -</option>
        <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="AL">Albania</option>
        <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
        <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But no, the ES6 is transpiled before consumption

Comment: this code does not work for you ?

Comment: what is 'this' if you log it? in you screenshot you debug arrow function so 'this' maybe belong to upper context

Comment: Actually, you were right!  I totally forgot about the upper context part.  Marking this as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

If the element has `id`, you can just use the `id` for the query selector. Then, you can find the selected option.

```js
$('#edit-country-code-country').change(function() {
    var $option = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var code = $option.val(); // to get selected country code
    var name = $option.text(); // to get selected country name
});
```