# HTML <Select> tag won't insert the dynamic value of the drop-down list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I wanted to create a form that will insert into a particular GSheet. All other fields are working (adding correctly to the GSheet file after submitting) but the dynamic drop-down list just inserts nothing even though, before submitting the form, the dynamic value is seen and able to be selected in the form.

Script:

```
<script>
  function loadItem() {
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
{
  var itemSelect = document.getElementById("CATEGORY");
  console.log(ar);
  
  let option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = "";
  option.text = "";
  itemSelect.appendChild(option);

  ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
  {    
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = item[1];
    option.text = item[0];
    itemSelect.appendChild(option);    
  });

}).getList();
};

 function onSelect() 
{
$("#CATEGORY option:selected").value();
};
</script>
```

HTML for the dropdown:

```
<label for="CATEGORY"><strong>CATEGORY</strong></label>
<select id="CATEGORY" onchange="onSelect()" class="form-control" name="CATEGORY" required>          
</select>
<script>
loadItem();                                
</script>
```

Code in Code.gs in my Google App Script for the GSheet:

```
function getList() { 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Category'); 
var getLastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();  
return dataSheet.getRange(2, 2, getLastRow - 1, 2).getValues();  
}
```

Form submit code:

```
function preventFormSubmit() {
            var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
            for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
                forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);
        function handleFormSubmit() {
            var formdata = $('#myForm').serializeArray()
            formdata.push({
              name: 'myfile',
              value: myfile
            })
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).processForm(formdata);
        }
        function success(){
             document.getElementById("myForm").reset()
             Swal.fire({
              position: 'center',
              icon: 'success',
              title: 'THE FILE HAS BEEN ADDED!',
              showConfirmButton: false,
              timer: 3500,
            })
            function Redirect() {
           window.location = "";
            }
            setTimeout(Redirect, 3000);
        }
    var myfile ={},file, reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function(e) {
      myfile.data = e.target.result
      myfile.name = file.name
      console.log(myfile)
  };
 $('#file').change(function(){
   file = $('#file')[0].files[0]
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 })
```

Form code in Code.gs

```
 function processForm(formdata){
 var superscript = SuperScript.initSuper(url,sh)
 var formObject = {}
 formdata.forEach(element => formObject[element.name] = 
 element.value)
 var file = superscript.uploadFile(folderId,formObject.myfile.data,formObject.myfile.name)
 var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
 var ws=ss.getSheets()[0]
 ws.appendRow([
 formObject.col1,
 formObject.col2,
          new Date(),
          formObject.TITLE,
          formObject.SUBTITLE,
          formObject.DESCRIPTION,
          formObject.TYPE,
          formObject.YEAR_RELEASED,
          formObject.CATEGORY,
          file.getUrl()
  ]);
  }
```

Comment: `.value()` should be `.val()`. You're also not doing anything with the value. And you don't need `option:selected` -- the value of a dropdown is the value of its selected option.

Comment: @Barmar I tried $("#CATEGORY").val(); but selected value still didn't appear on my Gsheet.

Comment: What are you expecting the `onSelect` function to do?

Comment: @JonP to add the selected value to the Gsheet file upon submission of the form.

Comment: Well, your onSelect function won't do that.  That will only fire when the select element is changed. Where is the form submit code?

Comment: Can you share code of any other field that is adding correctly to the GSheet file after submitting.?

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
return $('#CATEGORY').find(":selected").val();
```

The reason `val()` doesn't do the trick is because clicking an option doesn't change the value of the dropdown--it just adds the `:selected` property to the selected option which is a child of the dropdown.

also your function should return something in order for the output of it to be used.

Referred this answer:
[jQuery Get Selected Option From Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Comment: The selected value still didn't add :(

Comment: Added return keyword too?

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: Clicking on an option DOES change the value of the dropdown. I've used `$("#dropdown").val()` many times.

Comment: The return value of an `onchange` function isn't used. Why should the function return something?